# Failed to execute Raster to Point for multiple rasters in Model Builder

Tags: raster, modelbuilder, point, error-999999

I am trying to create Hotspot Analysis for multiple point shapefiles. For that, I am converting the rasters to point using `"Raster to Point"` tool in Model Builder.

It's converting the first file but giving error for the rest of the files. Here is the screenshot of the model.

How can I convert multiple rasters to point in the Model Builder?

[image: example]

Comment: Your path is looking weird with multiple dots in it, .tif.shp etc. Try fixing it

Comment: How to do that?